# Javascript stop "this" keyword from change on function call?

Tags: javascript, onclick, this, call, keyword

I was wondering. I've got a button from where I call a function when pressed. I use JQuery to do this as such:

```
this.chose_button.on('click', function() {
  tryInputSong(this, this.link_input.val());
});
```

the problem though is that I need the input parameter for "tryInputSong" to be the same object as the "this" keyword in "this.chose_button" not as the "this.chose_button" object itself. Is there a way I can stop the "this" keyword from changing the value to this.chose_button or must I in some way pass my wanted object through another function?

I am really confused about to solve this and I would appreciate some help, thank you! :)

Comment: `var oldThis = this` and then you can do `tryInputSong(oldThis, oldThis.link_input.val());`

Answer (score 3):

JS introduced arrow functions to allow you to reference the outer `this` value.

```
this.chose_button.on('click', event => 
  tryInputSong(this, this.link_input.val())
);
```

Because arrow functions don't bind their own local `this`, it uses the one from the outer environment.

The syntax I show above has a single expression as the function body. If you need multiple statements, then you define the body with curly braces, just like with traditional `function` syntax.

You can still get reference to the bound element via `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: availability of arrow funcitons depends on needed browser support and if you're transpiling or not with babel.

Comment: @lkroneman: Yes, very true.

Answer (score 2):

The usual old-school work-around is storing a reference to this from the context you want and reuse it later:

```
var self = this;
this.chose_button.on('click', function() {
  tryInputSong(self, self.link_input.val());
});
```

You can also explicitly bind the value of this on your function:

```
this.chose_button.on('click', function() {
  tryInputSong(this, this.link_input.val());
}.bind(this));
```

Or if your environment supports ES6 arrow functions (or you use a transpiler adds the corresponding polyfills), then you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which doesn't change the binding of `this`

```
this.chose_button.on('click', () => {
  tryInputSong(this, this.link_input.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var self = this;
this.chose_button.on('click', function() {
  tryInputSong(self, self.link_input.val());
});
```

Or use arrow functions: An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used